# How can I search a string in a very big file with a specific format in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [do searching in a very big ARPA file in a very short time in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127640/do-searching-in-a-very-big-arpa-file-in-a-very-short-time-in-java)

my file's format:

\data\

ngram 1=19

ngram 2=234

ngram 3=1013

\1-grams:

-1.7132 puluh -3.8008

-1.9782 satu -3.8368

\2-grams:

-1.5403 dalam dua -1.0560

-3.1626 dalam ini 0.0000

\3-grams:

-1.8726 itu dan tiga

-1.9654 itu dan untuk

\end\

As you can see I have a number of lines in ngram 1,2 and 3. There is no need to read the whole file. If an input string is a one-word string, the program can just search in \1-grams: part. If an input string is a two-word string, the program can just search in \2-grams: part and so on. At last if the program finds the input string in the file, it has to return two numbers which are located at the left and right sides of the string. Also, I have to say that each part of the file has been sorted. I am sure that I do not have to read the file completely, and using the index file can not solve my problem. These ways take a lot of time, and my lecturer said that searching has to be done in less than 1 minute for such a big file. I think the best thing is to find a way to jump to a specific line not byte of the file, but I do not know how I can do it. It will be great if someone can help me to solve my problem.

My file is almost 800MB. I have found that using BufferedReader is a good way to read a file very fast, but when I read such a big file and put it in an array line by line, it takes more than 30 minutes.

Comment: Is this homework? (you mention a lecture).  What have you tried so far?  Can you edit your question and show some of the code you have tried so far.

Comment: This is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127640/do-searching-in-a-very-big-arpa-file-in-a-very-short-time-in-java

Comment: Well unless you have a well defined structure and bytes of data known before hand you will need to scan whole file..  if in any way you can record the Byte position in the File and index it at Top of file there is no way AFAIK...

Answer (score 1):

How big is your file? A minute is a very long time. I would suggest using a BufferedReader for efficiency (and also for its `readLine` method).

If that really takes too long, two approaches come to mind that don't use indexes:

1. Force every line in the file to be the same length. Then you can jump to a specific line by calculating its start. If you don't know the line number you need, then at least you can use this to efficiently do a binary search of the entire file.
2. Jump to an arbitrary position and read forward until you get to a line that starts with a `\`. That will tell you whether you've found the right part or whether you need to jump forward from there or backward from the arbitrary position that you jumped to. This can also be used to create a binary search strategy for the data you need. It relies on the `\` being a reliable indicator of the start of a part.

Comment: Jumping to a line still involves reading the file from start to find `\n` and then count line numbers, so that is not efficient way

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro I think you missed his overarching solution of a modified binary search.  Yes, all lines that he reads he has to read the entire line.  But if he finds the middle of the file (one seek operation; no need to read every byte to get there) and find the next section heading to determine if the desired section is in the before-half or after half, you've eliminated reading almost half the file.  Doing that again in the chunk you've determined has the answer eliminates another quarter of the file, and so on.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro - if every line is the same length (my proposal #1), you don't have to count `\n`; just `seek()` to the position that starts the line you want, which you know because all lines are the same length.

Comment: exactly..that what i've said in my comment on the question...